# Can you specify an input/output folder (not bucket) for Elastic Transcoder?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to specify a folder within my S3 bucket for videos to be processed by Elastic Transcoder.  I also want those output videos to be in a different folder within the same bucket.  Is this possible?

This resource: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/latest/developerguide/job-settings.html#job-settings-general specifies that the input key can have a file prefix.  Would the file prefix here signify a folder directory in a bucket?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the documentation you linked, it specifies how to use a "key prefix" for both input and output files. A "key prefix" in S3 is analogous to a folder.